# cannot import name 'AzureSasCredential' from 'azure.core.credentials'

Tags: azure, databricks

On a Databricks 7.3 ML run time, I installed and imported azureml.core and get this error, Can you please help me solve this issue:

```
cannot import name 'AzureSasCredential' from 'azure.core.credentials' 
(/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/core/credentials.py)
```

Comment: How did you install the library?

Answer (score 1):

I reproduce same in environment with Databricks 7.3 ML run time. I got same error.

[image]

To resolve above error. Follow below steps:

```
!pip install azure-core
```

Then, update azure -core using below command:

```
!pip install --upgrade azure-core
```

After installing the package  , import `AzureSasCredential` as shown in below.

```
from azure.core.credentials import AzureSasCredential
```

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, though was importing `AzureKeyCCredential`